# Conditionally render a component on a click event in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

It's been a while since using Vue JS and I am currently attempting to render a list of data with a button for each record. When the button is clicked, I would like to conditionally render a component ( in this instance).

Is there a Vue approved way of doing this? Should I be manipulating the DOM? The following doesn't seem to work.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="data in list">
      {{ data.bar}}
      <button @click="handleClick">
        <div v-if="dataset.loading === 'true'">
          <loader/>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { loader } from './components'

    const list = [{ foo: 'bar'}];
    
    const handleClick = (el) => {
        el.dataset.loading = 'true';
        setTimeout(3, () => el.dataset.loading = 'false');
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Observation :***

- There is no object with `bar` key in the `list` array. Use `data.foo` instead of `data.bar`.

***Suggestions :***

- It is recommended to provide a `:key` with `v-for` whenever possible.
- Add `loading` property in each object of the list array. So that it will behave dynamically while setting the value `onClick`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [{ foo: 'bar', loading: false }]
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(dataIndex) {
      this.list[dataIndex].loading = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.list[dataIndex].loading = false;
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(data, index) in list" :key="index">
      {{ data.bar }}
      <button @click="handleClick(index)">
        <div v-if="data.loading">
          Loading Start
        </div>
        <div v-else> Loading Finish </div>
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The list of data will be coming from an ajax request. The signature of those objects will not contain a loading attribute. Are you suggesting I apply that property via Array.map or is there another way?

Comment: @Query Instead of `Array.map`, you can add that property via `Array.forEach()` with default value as false.

Comment: @Query did you tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ref` on your `list` variable to make it reactive. Also, you are accessing a `dataset` variable which doesn't exists in your application.

This is one way of doing it, I just added an extra data on your `list`

```js
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'


let list = ref([{ foo: 'bar', loading: 'true'}]);

const handleClick = (data) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      data.loading = 'false'
    },1000);
};

</script>

<template>

    <div v-for="data in list" >
      {{ data.foo}}
      <button @click="handleClick(data)"> //you can also use a `ref` here.
        <div v-if="data.loading === 'true'">
          Your Loader Component
        </div>
        <div v-else> 
          Something else...
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>
```

You can also use [Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)